# setup SDL2 mac through command line

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, sdl-2

I'm trying to setup SDL2 to use with g++, a text editor and terminal.

I have my SDL2.framework in /Library/Frameworks.

I have a folder on my desktop named testsdl which contains two files:

1. main.cpp
2. makefile

when I type make I get the following error:main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found.
here is a copy of my makefile

```
CXX = g++
SDL = -framework SDL2

CXXFLAGS = -Wall -c -std=c++11 -I ~/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers
LDFLAGS = $(SDL) -F /Library/Frameworks -F ~/Library/Frameworks/
EXE = SDL_Lesson0

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): main.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm *.o && rm $(EXE)
```

and here is a copy of main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
  {
    std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

I tried changing the #include to "SDL2/SDL.h" or just <sdl.h> or any other possible combination. I had no problem setting it up through Xcode but can't figure out how to do it without using an IDE.

a second part of the question is:
if I wanted to include the frameworks in the project folder itself so I can later distribute the binaries to people who do not have SDL on their machines how would I do that?

Comment: don't know the answer for sure but these things look suspicious to me: (1) why is there a space between `-I` and path `~/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers`? Normally there is not a space between `-I`, `-L`, `-l`, or any other compiler flags and their parameters. (2) Does `~/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/SDL2/SDL.h` actually exist? If not then there is your problem. (3) If you want the compilation to be cross-platform (i.e. work on linux / bsd / windows) then I guess you should stay away from `-framework` also and use `-L -l` instead

Comment: thanks, I tried removing the spaces but that did not help. The framework and the headers are all there

Comment: @ChrisBeck It works just as well with and without the space. It's true that it's usually without but that's not a limitation. (Sorry about the earlier comment if you saw it .. I realised that it could have come across as rude so I deleted it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track, but `-F /Library/Frameworks` needs to also be in the CXXFLAGS. The resulting commands should look something like:

```
g++ -Wall -F /Library/Frameworks -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ main.o -o main -framework SDL2 -I /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers
```

Here's a simplified makefile that works for me on OSX 10.12.6:

```
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS = -Wall -F /Library/Frameworks
LDFLAGS = -framework SDL2 -F /Library/Frameworks -I /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers

all: main

main: main.o
    $(CXX) main.o -o main $(LDFLAGS)

obj/main.o : main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp -o main.o

clean:
    rm main.o main
```

Comment: The linker doesn't need to know the -I include paths, that should be for the compiler, and you don't specify either -I or -framework in CXXFLAGS, so it's strange that you got the above to work :)

Answer (score 1):

if you go into

```
/Users/path/where/i/unzipped/SDL2-2.0.5
```

and run

```
sdl2-config --cflags --libs
```

it prints out the header include path and library path SDL

The full generic build probably looks something like:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe `sdl2-config --cflags` `sdl2-config --libs`
```

which you can translate into your make file if you like

Comment: Unfortunately sdl2-config doesn't come with the OSX SDL2 download. The  dmg file on https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php only contains the file SDL2.framework. It seems if you want sdl2-config you have to compile SDL2 from source first, or use homebrew/macports.